# ¿Como convertir fraccion a decimal en PHP 5.6?

Tags: php

Investigue pero no econtre resultados, solamente muchos usando `Javascript` como por ejemplo la siguiente funcion `eval`:

```
var numb = '1/2';
numb = eval( numb ); //Esto devuelve 0.5
```

Pero en `PHP` no encontre una funcion similar que haga lo mismo. Si sirve de algo, estoy usando `Laravel`, si me podria ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si haces lo siguiente:

```
$expression="1/2"; 
echo eval("echo $expression;");
```

Obtienes como resultado `0.5`

---

### Precaución

El constructor de lenguaje `eval()` es muy peligroso porque permite la ejecución de código de PHP arbitrario. Su uso está totalmente desaconsejado.

- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php

Por lo que en vez de usar esta opción, deberías buscar el modo de transformar el input textual a numérico y calcularlo como tal.
Para ello, lo mejor sería emplear alguna función, o procedimiento.

```
$num = "1/2";
$nnum = $explode = explode('/', $num);
$result = $nnum[0] / $nnum[1];
echo $result;
```

Comment: Lo que pasa esque tengo ese valor como un `string` (Lo saco de la DB) y si lo imprimo como me dices, me sale `1/2`

Comment: actualizada la respuesta @bemoba1437

Comment: Gracias, si esta demas, podrias explicarme que es codigo PHP arbitrario?

Comment: @bemoba1437 Excorpion se refiere a ejecutar código PHP no controlado, inyectado por algún usuario con motivos maliciosos. Debemos tener cuidado con nuestra programación, ya que pueden exponerse datos de nuestros usuarios o de nosotros mismos

Comment: Es tan cierto, que el código anterior, Windows me lo detectó como amenaza grave, y lo borró de inmediato.

Comment: Hola, como puedo convertir 0.5 en una fracción; es decir; convertirla en 1/2 otra vez?

Comment: Espero esto te ayude @albertolg89 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330713/converting-float-decimal-to-fraction